# How to detach/release surfaceview from android mediaplayer

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediaplayer

i have a mediaplayer instance running in a background service. In my main activity i have a surfaceview.

When the activity launches and the surfaceview is created i bind to the service and set the display surface of the mediaplayer to the surfaceview from my main activity. I do this with `mPlayer.setSurface(sv.getHolder().getSurface());`

The video is displayed and everything works fine so far. When my surfaceview is destroyed, in the `surfaceDestroyed()` callback i try to detach the surfaceview from the mediaplayer by calling `mPlayer.setSurface(null);`. The problem is that when i do this i get an error from the mediaplayer(error code 1).

So my question is this, after i have set up a MediaPlayer object and i set the surfaceview with `mPlayer.setSurface(sv.getHolder().getSurface());` is there a way to release or detach that surfaceview without stopping or reinitializing the mediaplayer object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you try to achieve removing the surface from the media player?

Comment: @Artjom what i'm trying to do is this: if the user closes the screen or navigates away from my main activity i want to continue playing the audio part of the video in the background. If the user reenters my activity and if a clip is playing in my background service i want to automatically display the video in my surfaceview. Is there any way i can do this without stopping or resetting the MediaPlayer object ?

Comment: @ilikekiwis I am trying to do the same thing here. Did you come up with an idea latter?

Comment: Do you try just don't pause playback when user close app screen (hide)? As I remember it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid pausing playback when user navigate away. This will help you continue playback. But there is another issue: when your activity/fragment detached from window `SurfaceView` became destroyed. Which means you HAVE TO reinitialize media player with recreated instance of `SurfaceView` when user returns back to your app.